# Cambiar el nombre del archivo pdf

Tags: c#, mvc, pdf

¿Cómo puedo hacer para ponerle un nombre a mi archivo generado en pdf en MVC al momento de presionar descargar? 
Es decir, es un poco compleja la pregunta, pero la idea es que al clickear sobre descargar muestre título y cuota. 
Dejo captura para que se entienda lo que quiero decir:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Presionamos el botón descargar y luego se nos abre el cuadro:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero saber si al nombre 100878.pdf se le puede agregar algo más de manera programada. Es decir, una vez que presione el botón descargar el nombre sea: 100878-08.pdf.

Dejo algo del código del pdf generado en MVC:

```
@model IEnumerable<ProviEntity.Models.ProvidusCuotas> 

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "DetailCustomer";
}


<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Inicio</title>


    <style>

        body {
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }

        .cheqAbajo {
            border-collapse: separate;
            border-spacing: 0px 5px;
        }

        .fechaSorteo {
            border-collapse: separate;
            border-spacing: 1px 5px;
        }

        .planAntes {
            border-collapse: separate;
            border-spacing: 1px 9px;
        }

        .valNomUno {
            border-collapse: separate;
            border-spacing: 1px 10px;
        }

        .valCero {
            border-collapse: separate;
            border-spacing: 1px 17px;
        }

        .valNomUlt {
            border-collapse: separate;
            border-spacing: 1px 17px;
        }

        .monto {
            border-collapse: separate;
            border-spacing: 1px 10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body style="background-image: url( ~/Images/prueba.png)">
    <br /><br /><br /><br />
    <div style="float:left">
        <table>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row" abbr="Suscriptor">Suscriptor: </th>
                    <td>
                        <b>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.apellido), @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.nombre)
                        </b>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row" abbr="Domicilio">Domicilio: </th>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.domicilio)
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row" abbr="Barrio">Barrio: </th>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.barrio)
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row" abbr="Localidad">Localidad: </th>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.localidad)
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row" abbr="Telefono">Teléfono: </th>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.telefono)
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr></th>
                    <th scope="row" abbr="Celular">Celular: </th>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.celular)
                    </td>
                </tr>

            }
        </table>
    </div>

    @*-----------------------------------------------DATOS DE DERECHA DE LA CHEQUERA---------------------------------------------------------------**@
    <br />
    <div style="float:right">
        @**Fecha Sorteo*@
        <table class="fechaSorteo">
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td><b>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.fechaSorteo)</b></td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
    </div>

    <br /><br /><br />
    <div style="float:right">
        @*Plan Anterior*@
        <table class="planAntes">
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.planantes)</b>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
    </div>

    <br /><br /><br />
    <div style="float:right">
        @*Valor Nominal*@
        <table class="valNomUno">
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.valnom)</b>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
    </div>

    <br /><br /><br />
    <div style="float:right">
        @*Valor en Cero*@
        <table class="valCero">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <b>$0</b>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <br /><br /><br />
    <div style="float:right">
        @*Valor Nominal**@
        <table class="valNomUlt">
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td align="right">
                        <b>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.valnom)</b>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div>
        @*Descripción*@
        <table>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <b>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.descplanactual)</b>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
    </div>

    <br />
    <div style="float:right">
        @*Monto = Importe*@
        <table class="monto">
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.monto)</th>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
    </div>
    <div>
        <table class="cheqAbajo">
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.acidzona)</th>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.cobrador)</th>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.codigo)</th>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.titulo)/@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.endoso)</th>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.sorteo)</th>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.cuota)</th>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.vencimiento)</th>@*vencimiento*@
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: El código de la Vista es irrelevante. Indica por favor el código del Controlador y la Acción donde generas el PDF, y el código del botón "descargar".

Comment: Lo que tendrás que hacer en el backend es generar una cabecera de respuesta de tipo "Content-Disposition" con valor "attachment; filename=108788.pdf" o el nombre de fichero que necesites. Quizás alguien te pueda ayudar con el código concreto en C# para hacerlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu controlador, antes de tu `return`, debes agregar un encabezado a la respuesta.

```
public ActionResult GenerarPdf()
{
    ...
    Response.Clear();
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"NOMBRE DEL ARCHIVO.pdf\"");
    // "attachment" es para forzar una descarga, puedes sustituirlo por "inline" para que el
    // navegador lo abra en una nueva pestaña.

    // En caso de que generes un Stream:
    return new FileContentResult(bytesDelArchivo, "application/pdf");
    // En caso de que lo hagas por una ruta de archivo físico:
    return File(rutaDelArchivo, "application/pdf");
}
```

Comment: Gracias me ha servido, agregué la línea de la cabecera y funcionó de maravilla